# Regression Analysis and Conditional Expectation

Tags: statistics

I have to calculate a Expectation of some expression conditioned on something. I know alpha, Beta1 and Beta2 in the below expression. Income and Family_Size are 2 Uniform Random Variables between 0 and 1.  I don't know the Cutoff_income & Cutoff_Family_Size which will be constants. Can the following expression be used to calculate [Cutoff_income - Cutoff_Family_Size] since I already know the R.H.S? If yes, how ? I need to make a decision based on this, as lets say someone has some income and family_size then if I know the Cutoff_income and Cutoff_Family, I can reject or accept him for my analysis.

**E[Alpha + Beta1*Income + Beta2*Family_Size | (Income - Family_Size > Cutoff_income - Cutoff_Family_Size ) ] = 0.25**

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You'll get more interest in this question at stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks. Will do so now.